# How can I add the session name to my screen status display?

Tags: gnu-screen

This is my current .screenrc files which is mostly copied from the link in the code

```
#First iteration 2014-09-06, not quite sure of stuff to add
# got a fancy hardstatus line noted below
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
# hardstatus string "%w"

# blagged this hardstatus like from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=55618, not quite sure what it does
hardstatus string '%{= kG}%{C}Screen: %{c}%{= kG}[%= %{= kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{C} %d-%m %{W}%c %{g}]'
```

I now want the session name to appear in it as well, and the one I have settled on is from this answer - https://superuser.com/questions/212392/how-to-include-screens-session-name-in-hardstatus/212520#212520

The solution runs along these line:

```
hardstatus string '%H:%`'
backtick 0 30 30 sh -c 'screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*"'
```

It is an area I am not familiar with and I wonder how the `backtick` command fits in it, ie whether it is a `screen` command at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Backtick) or better you can check `man` page for `screen` which is a good reference and says:

> **backtick** id lifespan autorefresh cmd args...
>   **backtick** id
>
> Program the backtick command with the numerical id id.  The output of such a command is used for substitution of the "%`" string escape. The specified `lifespan` is the number of seconds the output is considered valid. After
>   this time, the command is run again if a corresponding string escape is encountered.  The `autorefresh` parameter triggers an automatic refresh for caption and hardstatus strings after the specified number of  seconds.  Only
>   the last line of output is used for substitution.
>   If  both  the `lifespan` and the `autorefresh` parameters are zero, the backtick program is expected to stay in the background and generate output once in a while.  In this case, the command is executed right away and screen
>   stores the last line of output. If a new line gets printed screen will automatically refresh the hardstatus or the captions.
>          The second form of the command deletes the backtick command with the numerical id id.

As per your example you can add:

```
hardstatus string '%H:%1` | %2`'
backtick 1 30 30 sh -c 'screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*"'
backtick 2 60 60 /usr/bin/uptime
```

Comment: If you have more than one `backtick` command in the `screenrc` how do you select the output of the one you want to display, or are you restricted to just one `backtick` command?

Comment: You can select by id. The %id` string escape will put the specified backtick output into the status.

Comment: @vfclists, I added simple example. Hope it helps.