# How can I stop zsh (oh-my-zsh) from resetting screen window titles?

Tags: zsh, gnu-screen, oh-my-zsh

Whenever I create a new window in `gnu screen` I usually give it a name which persists between disconnects, but I notice that with `oh-my-zsh` distribution of `zsh` the title gets reset when I run a command in the window. Basically it gets reset to `(x* ~)` where `x` is the window number.

Not only that when I run a command in remote session in that window the title which was set locally gets changed to the command run in the remote window if the remote shell is `zsh`. This doesn't happen with `bash`.

e.g. lets say I create a new window in screen with the title as `(2* ~)` and then set the title to `user@remotehost` because I am going to connect to `remotehost` as `user`. When I run `ssh user@remotehost` to connect to `remotehost` the title reverts to `(2* ~)`. When in `remotehost` I run `htop` the title changes to `htop` which I don't want.

It seems as though `zsh` is propagating the remote windows command into the local window's title even if it is connected to another session. This seems to happen only under `zsh` as it never happens with `bash`. Is there some setting  `zsh` or `oh-my-zsh` that overrides the previous behaviour? I haven't changed by `.screenrc` on switch to `zsh` and here it is.

```
# got a fancy hardstatus line noted below
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
# hardstatus string "%w"

# blagged this hardstatus like from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=55618, not quite sure what it does
# extended from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195209 and , uptime command disabled
# http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/String-Escapes.html#String-Escapes
hardstatus string '%{= kG}%{C}Screen:%{Rk}Host:%H %1`%{c}%{= kG}[%= %{= kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{C} %d-%m %{W}%c %{g}]'
backtick 1 30 30 sh -c 'screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*" | cut -d '.' -f 2'
# backtick 2 60 60 /usr/bin/uptime
```

Comment: This is done through `precmd` and `preexec` functions, or through the prompt. Since you're using oh-my-zsh, there may be a setting to disable it, otherwise you'll have to set those functions/variables manually.

Comment: The best solution is to disable oh-my-zsh, there is nothing you couldn't set by yourself, and a lot of useless garbage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be disabled in `.zshrc` by uncommenting the line:

```
# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title. 
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"
```

It is applied in the functions `omz_termsupport_precmd` and `omz_termsupport_preexec`, which are in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/termsupport.zsh`